# PHP - How to DRY repetitive database queries and html blocks?

Tags: php, dry

I have a situation of repeating identical database query, and identical related HTML on various places in application.

So what is the usual/best practice way of DRYing this?

Includes work perfectly for this situation, but if I adopt that as 
method of DRYing, may I eventually end up with too many includes slowing down the app?

Comment: Don't worry about slowing down, use something like APC and this is a non-problem.

Comment: the usual/best practice way of DRYing this -> refactoring, e.g. [extract method](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try having a central file for database queries and only including it where you need it. Similarly for html fragments.

You might find an MVC pattern useful in this instance (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: Zend Framework and CodeIgniter would be two excellent examples of a PHP MVC framework.  Zend Framework has a caching feature which can minimize unnecessary calls to the DB

Comment: @Arno: sounds interesting, is there any example/tutorial you can point me to, that shows a concrete implementation?

Comment: Depending on the programming language that you use, you can have a look at the Wikipedia link and pick an example in the languages section (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller#Implementations_as_web-based_frameworks). Most of them have tutorials that can guide you.

Comment: @Arno: that link provided a wealth of useful further links, recommended to anyone interested in this question.

Answer (score 1):

I usually make utility classes with static methods that handle echoing of repeated blocks. For example take a look at my classes for [`social plugins`](https://github.com/nicoladj77/SocialPlugins)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to roll your own - at least partly, and not use a complete framework, you can mix some of the well established libraries and decouple logic from templates.

For example, what I do is use Smarty - a well established templating engine - and extend its base class to do cheap queries.

Normally you would use Smarty in this fashion, separating your logic from templates:

```
$Smarty = new Smarty();
$Smarty->assign( 'myvariable', array( ... ) ); // usually a database query return
$Smarty->display( 'template.tpl' );
```

So I've extended it to do queries:

```
class QSmarty extends Smarty {
    function query( $sql ) {
        $args = func_get_args();
        $sql = array_shift( $args );
        foreach( $args as $k => $v ) $args[$k] = mysql_escape_string( $v );
        $safe_sql = vsprintf( $sql, $args );

        // assuming this will be manageable (paginated or reasonably sized)
        $ret = array();
        $t = mysql_query( $safe_sql );
        while( $r = mysql_fetch_assoc( $t ) ) {
            $ret[] = $r;
        }
        return( $ret );
    }
}
```

Thus you can lazily use this over and over again:

```
$Smarty = new QSmarty();
$Smarty->assign( 'users', $Smarty->query(
    "select * from users where group=%s",
    $_GET['group'] // gets sanitized automatically
));

$Smarty->display( 'users.tpl' );
```

Template file users.tpl might look like this:

```
<ul>
{foreach $users as $user}
    <li class="{cycle values='odd,even'} {if $user@last}last_user{/if}">
        {$users.id}: {$users.username|lower}
    </li>
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

Since Smarty supports template inheritance, custom template functions, and a nest of other capabilities, you can segment reusable HTML into their own individual files and use templating markup such as {include users.tpl} inside other templates, assigning and reassigning variables as you see fit. Very DRY.

Truth be told, yeah, this is pretty much a sales pitch for Smarty, demonstrating or highlighting just some of its capabilities.  Query aside, Smarty is doing all the heavy lifting here.  Give it, or another templating engine, a whirl.